# ClassNotFound for AppletLoader when exporting a libGDX applet

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, libgdx

I tried following [this](http://www.thesecretpie.com/2011/05/being-like-minecraft-or-how-to-run-your.html) to export my libGDX game as a Java applet. The guide was a bit confusing so I might have done something wrong here. This is what I did:

---

My libGDX game, in Eclipse, looks like this:

```
Game
Game-Android
Game-Desktop
```

The desktop game works fine.

As the guide says, the desktop project uses the Lwjgl backend.

---

Then I created a `GameApplet.java` in `Game-Desktop/src/my.package.name` containing

```
package my.package.name;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplet;

public class GameApplet extends LwjglApplet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public GameApplet()
    {
        super(new Game(), false);
    }
}
```

---

I created a directory `applet` in `Game` containing

```
gdx.jar
gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar
gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar
gdx-natives.jar
lwjgl_util_applet.jar
```

---

I right-clicked `Game` in Eclipse and exported it as a JAR with the following settings:

```
Resources to export:
 - Game
   -- src
   -- libs
Export generated class files and resources
```

The exported JAR (called `Applet.jar`) was placed in the `applet` folder.

---

I created the `index.html` file containing

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HelloApplet!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="applet_container">
  <applet code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" archive="lwjgl_util_applet.jar" codebase="." width="640" height="480">

    <param name="al_title" value="HelloApplet">
    <param name="al_main" value="my.package.name.GameApplet">

    <param name="al_bgcolor" value="000000">
    <param name="al_fgcolor" value="ffffff">

    <param name="al_jars" value="Applet.jar, gdx.jar, gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar">

    <param name="al_windows" value="gdx-natives.jar, gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar">
    <param name="al_linux" value="gdx-natives.jar, gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar">
    <param name="al_mac" value="gdx-natives.jar, gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar">
    <param name="al_solaris" value="gdx-natives.jar, gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar">

    <param name="codebase_lookup" value="false">

    <param name="java_arguments" value="-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dsun.java2d.opengl=false -Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false -Xmx800M">
   <param name="lwjgl_arguments" value="-Dorg.lwjgl.input.Mouse.allowNegativeMouseCoords=true">
    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
    <param name="codebase_lookup" value="false">
  </applet>
  </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

---

I signed the files and uploaded them to my site. On Firefox, OSX, I get a message saying

```
ClassNotFoundException

org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader
```

---

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Which lwjgl_util_applet.jar are you using?

Comment: as P.T. suggested try to load 2.7.1 as it is used by the developer during its making-- as he wrote in his blog "It's 2.7.1 as I write it. Copy lwjgl-2.7.1/jar/lwjgl_util_applet.jar to your applet dir."

Comment: http://lightweight-java-game-library.soft112.com/

think that link is authenticate but prefer to checking in google before dwnlding anything!!